# correct way to instantiate bunch of classes at once

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection

I have a class `Main.java` in which I need to instantiate a bunch of other classes say `C1.java` ... `C50.java`. I am not able to think of an elegant way to instantiate these 50 classes in Main class. If I simply put all instantiating code in one place it looks so crowded and ugly. Today I have `50` classes to instantiate, tomorrow this count can increase to `100`, then this situation will get worse. Can you please suggest an elegant way of instantiating all these classes without making Main class crowded with instantiation code. I am not aware of any design pattern to do this.

I am thinking to create an array of classes that needs to be instantiated and use reflection to instantiate them.

Comment: Are you sure it's a correct design?

Comment: *Why* do you have 50 classes to init, do they really have a counter in their name, that is a big red flag!?

Comment: Are they related somehow, implements the same interface for instance ?

Comment: Are you also sure the classes' name follow a certain pattern? Ex. `Class1`, `Class2` ... `Class3`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Yes, they all implement same interface.

Comment: Main a list of all the classes, instantiate those classes using reflection and I assume that all the classes have the same interface.

Comment: @luk2302: No, they does not have counter in their name. All classes perform a calculation based on formula. Formula is different for each calculation and can not be generalized, thats why so many classes.

Comment: I agree that a better design is something to look into. But maybe try looking at the Factory Design Pattern too? Here's an example in Python: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_factory.htm

Comment: @JustBlossom: I don't think factory pattern is a good fit here as I have to instantiate all classes and there is not condition which defines which class needs to be instantiated when.

Comment: Since you are using java I suggest use [spring](https://spring.io/) `ApplicationContext.xml` or `Config bean classes` and load it in your main method. Sample is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm) . Spring internally uses reflection.
But it is the clean way that I can think of than directly using reflection.

Comment: `MyStrangeClass.class` and `new MyStrangeClass()` aren't much different in length, so using reflection probably wont help. Reflection is almost always a mistake anyway. If the difference in the classes is minimal, you may find replacing them with lambdas expressions helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what purpose the classes would serve. However, if you don't mind to end up with an unordered collection of instantiated classes, there is a way to go using [Reflections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10) library and I guess also a shorted one in the matter of lines of code:

```
// find out all the classes implementing MyInterface
Set<Class<? extends MyInterface>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(MyInterface.class);

// iterate those classes and instntinate them
List<MyInterface> objects = new ArrayList<>();
for (Class<? extends MyInterface> clazz: subtypes) {
    objects.add(clazz.newInstance());
}
```

In any case, the whole design should be rethough.

Comment: Mind that `clazz.newInstance()` has been deprecated in Java 9 for its subversion of Java’s exception handling rules. You should use `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution is to use the [service loader architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Instantiating all registered implementations of `MyInterface` can be done as simple as

```
for(MyInterface my: ServiceLoader.load(MyInterface.class)) {
    /* do something with <my> */
}
```

To make this work, its not enough to just implement the interface, these implementations must be declared as service providers, either via an entry in `META-INF/services/` of your jar file (as described in the linked class documentation) or via `provides` declaration within a Java module declaration when using Java 9 or newer.

The advantage of this is not only a higher performance, compared to searching the entire class path with a reflection library, it also ensures that the necessary access rights are established when using Java’s module system in the future.

See also [Java 9’s version of the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/util/ServiceLoader.html).